# Why do characters disappear when renaming files in Windows command line using wildcards?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to rename files from the format `IMG_20190618_xxxx.jpg` to `2019-06-18_RS_xxxx.jpg` where xxxx is a unique 5 digit numeric identifier.

Using the Windows command prompt, I tried

```
ren *_*_* 2019-06-18_RS_*
```

The outcome of this was what I wanted EXCEPT the first digit of the unique numeric identifier was missing, like this: `2019-06-18_RS_xxx.jpg`.  The first digit had been different in every case.

Please note I have now managed to rename the files using PowerShell, but what I want to know is: Why does the first digit after the last underscore disappear?

Thanks.

Comment: CMD's wildcard support is not a regular expression system that matches and substitutes groups, though even if it were it's not clear to me what you're thinking here. Why do you expect the "\*" in the destination name to match the last wildcard group in the source name?

Comment: In practice, matching "\*\_\*\_\*" in CMD is implemented by the filesystem, not the shell. Then the shell substitutes from the source to the destination name, with basic wildcard support. "2019-06-18\_RS\_" in the destination name is 14 characters, i.e. index values 0 to 13, so the "\*" wildcard in the destination name matches whatever is left in the source name, starting at index 14.